# C# Triple-Des incorrect length

Tags: c#, encryption, tripledes

I am trying to make an encrypt/decrypt code for 3DES using C# built in 3Des.
I am configuring it like this:

```
    this.tDes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider ();
    this.tDes.Key = new byte[]{97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112};
    this.tDes.IV = new byte[8];
    this.tDes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
```

And this is my decript function:

```
    public string Decrypt(string CipherText)
    {
        byte[] cipherData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(CipherText);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, this.tDes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cs.Write(cipherData, 0, cipherData.Length);
        cs.FlushFinalBlock();
        byte[] ClearBytes = ms.ToArray();
        ms.Close();
        cs.Close();
        string decriptedData = Convert.ToBase64String(ClearBytes);
        return decriptedData;
    }
```

This is my encrypt function:

```
public string Encrypt(string InputText)
{
    byte[] clearData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(InputText);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, this.tDes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    cs.Write(clearData, 0, clearData.Length);
    cs.FlushFinalBlock();
    byte[] CipherBytes = ms.ToArray();
    ms.Close();
    cs.Close();
string EncryptedData = Convert.ToBase64String(CipherBytes);
    return EncryptedData;
}
```

But when trying to decrypt it, C# throws an error in the line "cs.FlushFinalBlock();" saying incorrect length.
What should be the correct size?
What is the problem?

Comment: Hold up, your function is called `decrypt` but it appears to be encrypting the data. What is `decrypt` supposed to do?

Comment: Also you should look in to the [.NET Capitalization Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), your function should be `PascalCasing` and your local variables should all be `camaelCasing`.

Comment: Hold up, from your edit now it looks like you are using `UTF8.GetBytes` for it's input but in your old "encrypt" version you had `ToBase64` for it's output. Please post both your encrypt and your decrypt function. The error you are getting is almost always because your decrypt function does not match your encrypt function so we need to see both at the same time to compare the two. Also if you had not been getting a exception your function would just output the text `System.Byte[]`.

Comment: In your latest update what happened to `EncryptedData = Convert.ToBase64String(CipherBytes);`? It is kinda nessesary for your code to work.

Comment: Take a look at the text that `CipherBytes.ToString ();` is outputting. it is not your encrypted data... When you end up fixing that you will need to use `FromBase64String` to go back to `byte[]` from `string` in your `Decrypt` method.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. So I re-added that line, and I am still getting getting the same error about the length.. (but now I have the encrypted text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decode the base 64 before decrypting it (so assign it to `cipherData`). Then `clearBytes` should be decoded using UTF8 and assigned to `decriptedData`.